# ajaxoptions bootstrap-table, how to use? example anywhere?

Tags: bootstrap-table

I have scoured the internet and looked for how to use the bootstrap-table to send a simple object to the server using the ajaxOptions data property during it's request. The examples that are available have either been removed or just don't seem to work as I would expect.

I have the following code

```
    var obj = { "Facilities": ['1234', '123456'] };

    $('#tablePolicies').bootstrapTable({
        url: '/api/PolicyConfigurationAPI/getPoliciesInFacilities',
        method:"POST",
        ajaxOptions: {data: JSON.stringify(obj)},
        showFilter: true,
        idField: 'PolicyID',
        columns: [{
            field: 'state',
            checkbox: true
        },
            {
                field: 'Description',
                title: 'Description',
                sortable: true
            }]
    })
```

Calling the following c# mvc service...

`public HttpResponseMessage getPoliciesInFacilities(List Facilities) //this does have string in <> but the stackoverflow viewer has removed it 
{}`

I have tried several different combinations of options and the custom ajax call back/override.

However, I look in f12 and see the only data being sent is the standard (limit=10&offset=0&sort=id&order=asc)

What am I missing? I'm sure it must be simple, any help greatly appreciated.

Note: This works when using an extra $.ajax call and providing the returned json data to the data property of the table constructor, however this the fails to initialise the filters from bootstrap-table-filter'

Thanks

Ted

Comment: obj in this case is undefined btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this example where you can find a example code: http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/#issues/152.html